# Imgaug Augmenters - Shear Transformation

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, data-augmentation

I have been playing with the `imgaug.augmenters` library and am having some problems with shearing my image. I can shear the image, but depending on the image, some of the corners get chopped off. I had the same problem when rotating an image with `imutils.rotate`, but found a solution (`imutils.rotate_bound`). I was wondering if there is something similar in regards to shearing?

```
import imageio
import imgaug.augmenters
import os
from PIL import Image

os.chdir("C:\\Users\\name\\Desktop\\training\\JPEG")

j = 0
gaussian_noise = imgaug.augmenters.AdditiveGaussianNoise(5, 10)
for infile in os.listdir("C:\\Users\\name\\Desktop\\training\\JPEG"):
    image = imageio.imread(infile)
    shear_range = imgaug.augmenters.Affine(shear=(0, 40))
    shear = shear_range.augment_image(image)
    shear_output = Image.fromarray(shear)
    os.chdir("C:\\Users\\name\\Desktop\\shear_test")
    filename = 'noise' + str(j) + '.jpeg'
    shear_output.save("C:\\Users\\name\\Desktop\\shear_test\\" + filename)
    os.chdir("C:\\Users\\name\\Desktop\\training\\JPEG")
    j = j + 1
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: as I remeber author of `imutils` and `cv2` in some post on his blog described how it created `.rotate_bound` - and it is code in Python so you can see it and create something similar.

Comment: [Rotate images (correctly) with OpenCV and Python](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/01/02/rotate-images-correctly-with-opencv-and-python/)

Comment: Another possibility would be to PIL's rotate function. Just keep expand=True in its function.
https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html